# When changing a variable within if / else block an error says it is unassigned

Tags: c#, if-statement, unassigned-variable

I am trying to change the color of a ball randomly however when I try to use the color variable to become the color of the solid brush it says that it is unassigned.  "Use of unassigned local variable 'ballColour'"

```
    xPos = xPos + GAP_SIZE;
    int colour = rand.Next(1, 40);
    Color ballColour;
    if (colour >= 1 && colour <= 9)
    {
        ballColour = Color.Blue;
    }
    else if (colour >= 10 && colour <= 19)
    {
        ballColour = Color.Orange;
    }

    else if (colour >= 20 && colour <= 29)
    {
        ballColour = Color.Green;
    }
    else if (colour >= 30 && colour <= 39)
    {
        ballColour = Color.Red;
    }
    else if (colour == 40)
    {
        ballColour = Color.Purple;
    }
    SolidBrush ballColourBrush = new SolidBrush(ballColour); //This is the one that returns the error.
    paper.FillEllipse(ballColourBrush, xPos, yPos, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE);
                    xPos = xPos + BALL_SIZE;
```

Answer (score 4):

The compiler doesnt know that your if/else block is all-inclusive, so it is warning that `ballColour` may be unassigned.  A simple change to `rand.Next(1, 40);` without updating the if/else block and it may not be.

**Remedy 1: Initialize to something**

```
Color ballColour = Color.White;
```

**Remedy 2: Use an else:**

```
...
else                //if (colour == 40)
{
    ballColour = Color.Purple;
}
```

This allow the compiler to "see" a value is set for any and all cases.

**Remedy 3: All the above**

Initialize to the first value and skip the first test to reduce code:

```
Color ballColour = Color.Blue;

if (colour >= 10 && colour <= 19)
...
else     
{
    ballColour = Color.Purple;
}
```

**Note** that the second param to `Random.Next(min, max)` is *exclusive*, so the value can never be 40.  You probably want `rand.Next(1, 41)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, there is a chance that none of the if conditions are satisfied during the execution and at the time of executing the below line of code, the variable "ballColour" could be unassigned.

`SolidBrush ballColourBrush = new SolidBrush(ballColour);`

Comment: This answer is fine enough, but it says exactly what the already existing one says, with less explanation. Not really sure why you added it.